# Run R script from Powershell

Tags: r, windows, powershell

In batch script, I can run an R script with the following syntax:

```
Rterm.exe --quiet --slave --vanilla < "C:\some_script.R"
```

However, Powershell seems to have reserved "<" for future expansion. I am wondering if there is a direct way to run R script within another Powershell script.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should probably look `Rscript` instead of redirection -- this would become

```
Rscript.exe C:\someScript.R
```

where you can add the usual options.

Comment: For anyone visiting this page now (and I know it's 5 years old), there's a more general answer for running external programs and redirecting stdin to powershell at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478535/how-can-i-execute-an-external-program-with-parameters-in-powershell . Clearly though Rscript is a better option than Rterm for this.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is probably to wrap it in a call to cmd.exe:

```
cmd.exe /C "Rterm.exe --quiet --slave --vanilla < `"C:\some_script.R`""
```