# How to run a R language(.r) file using Batch file?

Tags: r, batch-file

I want to run a R script file (.r) using batch file.

Comment: I don't know what .r script file is; however, you must remember that a Batch file is just an automated way to execute DOS commands, so the answer to your question is: How do you run a R script file with a DOS command? If you can't do that via a command line, then a Batch file can't do either...

Comment: if you're still out there could you please help resolve the controversy here (see comment threads below)?

Comment: Hardy: in response to your other question (calling r from .net): see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025340/call-r-programming-language-from-net

Answer (score 54):

If R.exe is in your PATH, then your windows batch file (.bat) would simply consist of one line:

```
R CMD BATCH your_r_script.R
```

otherwise, you need to give the path of R.exe, so for example:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.0\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH your_r_script.R
```

you can add certain input arguments to the BATCH command, such as `--no-save`, `--no-restore`

so it would be

```
R CMD BATCH [options] your_r_script.R
```

more info on options, etc at http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/BATCH.html

Note: R uses the command "BATCH" to non-interactively evaluate a script located in a file. Here we are running the command "BATCH" from a windows .BAT file, but that's merely a coincidence.

Comment: Why flag?  Why not just downvote/encourage @mac to edit the answer? This answer tells how to run an R script from the command line, which is the missing piece of information that the OP was looking for, and which neither of the other answers provides ...

Comment: @Ben: Did you realize that mac have been a Stack Overflow member for just 3 days and that this answer is his first and only participation in this forum? He has earned all his 12 points from this answer (and your upvote)! I think is very disappointing for me that his answer had caused a -2 qualification in my record...

Comment: @Aacini: So?  It's a useful answer.  As I said, I can't remove my downvote at the moment, but if you edit your answer (even slightly) then I'll remove it ...

Comment: @Aacini: Since some were confused, I've edited my response to be a little more explicit that the code examples provided are what you would include in a Windows/DOS .BAT file. My original response was not, I think you'll find, out of context.

Answer (score 24):

[An answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582150/run-r-script-from-powershell) suggests using Rscript.exe, so your batch file would contain:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\i386\Rscript.exe"  your_script.R
pause
```

It is a good idea to add R to the windows environment path. In a comment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940022/running-r-interactively-from-windows-command-prompt) @chase gave a link that explains [how to set the path on windows 7](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx). Once R is added to the windows path, your batch file should become simply :

```
Rscript.exe  your_script.R
pause
```

You can also directly call a R command by using the -e flag. For example this batchfile will tell R to set its current working directory to Documents, then it will print the working directory:

```
Rscript.exe -e setwd('Documents');getwd()
pause
```

Comment: I prefer this solution with Rscript.exe over mac's solution with R.exe because with Rscript.exe I can see the output of my script (generated e.g. by cat()) on the command prompt, whereas with R.exe I can't see it.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with the syntax with the answers below, but this worked for me in the .bat file:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k ""path to Rscript.exe" 
"path to .R script""
```

Be sure to place both the path to Rscript.exe and the script in "" together and separately as above.

Answer (score -10):

I doubt you will be able to run it using a batch file.

http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/r
Most known programs that use .r files do so for source code files it looks like.  You will probably have to compile it using the program it was written for.  I guess you could use a command line compiler from a batch file, but I don't know what language or applications you are using.

If you post the script file or give more information about it, we could probably help you better.

Comment: do you know how to use R script in .net?