# Passing script as parameter to RGui

Tags: r, command-line

I was wondering if it possible to pass parameters to RGui from command prompt in windows.
I would like to do something like

```
RGui myScript.r param1 param2
```

just like I would do with RScript but I need to display a GUI.

Here is some more info regarding my needs.
I want to embedd a gui written in R in my C# forms application. What would happen is I press a button in the form and the application launches a process that calls RGui with my script and some parameters. This has worked fine so far with RScript but now that I am displaying graphics I need R to be in interactive mode. 
Here is the code I am using:

```
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName =Pathing.GetUNCPath( r_path) + "\\Rscript";
        string script_path=Directory.GetParent(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName.ToString();
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = Pathing.GetUNCPath(script_path) + "\\display.r " + data_path;
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;           
        myProcess.Start();
        myProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Prettymuch a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940022/running-r-interactively-from-windows-command-prompt

Comment: @Jack Maney : Oh no, it isn't. There is a VERY big difference between Rscript and RGui. In fact, what OP asks here is very possible with Rscript, and imho highly impossible with RGui.

Comment: @Jack, I don't think it's a duplicate. This question is asking if you can send objects (or calls) across instances of R while the Q you link to is asking how to launch an interactive session of R.

Comment: @Bogdan_s02 Please, rephrase your question and give us a bit more background. If this is linked to your previous question, and eg related to webdesign, you might want to tell us, as you'll need a very different approach than what you're doing now. If both questions deal with the same problem, explain it so we can merge both questions and actually give you the advice you need. PS : You can edit your question, please do so and don't post a new one.

Comment: @Joris: I love gradations of "impossible" - very highly impossible is the best yet.  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As said, you normally cannot do that. If you hack into your `Rprofile` or `Rprofile.site` ( see ?Startup for more information, or [this site](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html)), you can go around that, but the code is not portable to other computers. So if you feel really lucky and daring, you can try to do the following.

You add this code to your `Rprofile` file or `Rprofile.site` (which can be found in the /etc folder of your R install):

```
Args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
if(length(Args)>0 & sum(grepl(" -f ",commandArgs()))==0 ){          
    if(grepl("(?i).r$",Args[1])){
        File <- Args[1]
        Args <- Args[-1]
        tryCatch(source(File) , error=function(e) print(e) )
    }
}
```

This will allow you to do :

```
Rgui --args myscript.r arg1 arg2
Rscript myscript.r arg1 arg2
R --args myscript.r arg1 arg2
R -f myscript.r --args arg1 arg2
```

The --args argument will take care of the popups that @iterator warns for. The code will result in a variable `Args` which is contained in the base environment (which is *not* .GlobalEnv!). This variable contains all arguments apart from the filename. You can subsequently access that one from your script, eg:

```
#dumb script
print(Args)
```

If called with `Rgui` or `R`, there will also be a variable File that contains the name of the file that has been sourced.

Be reminded that changing your rProfile is not portable to other computers. So this is for personal use only. You can also not give -f as a parameter after --args, or you'll get errors.

Edit: We better search for " -f " than "-f" as this can occur in "path/to/new-files/".

Comment: +1 Brilliant!  Mad!  I believe that the same should apply for any file pointed to by `R_PROFILE` in the environment variable, so it need not be in the `.Rprofile` file.  But, I'm not a master of this like @Joris.  ;-)

Comment: I'm favoriting this question because of this answer.  It's genius.

Answer (score 3):

(UPDATED) WARNING: This will "work" but it is extremely ill-advised.  As far as I can tell, Rgui is not meant to take such script parameters.  @Joris pointed out to me the list of acceptable parameters is listed in `Rgui --help`.

If you follow the method below, some people will think you are on your way to madness.  On the other hand, mad people may think you're a genius.  All will agree that you should not do this in stuff that they use.

End of warnings.

If the script is named `.Rprofile` it will be sourced.  If you create a `.Rprofile` file (or environment variable) that reads `commandArgs()` then you can set it up to parse the command line.

You will get errors/ignore popups from R.  That's to identify that a bad thing has been done.

For what it's worth, this may be on the to-do list for Rstudio: http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/823-pass-command-line-parameters-to-r

Comment: And break a whole lot of other things, including being absolutely unportable. If anybody gives me code like that, I might consider buying a rifle...

Comment: @Joris: If you wait until then, it may be too late.  :)

Comment: As in "...not (yet) naming...".

Comment: To the OP: Please accept @Joris' answer.  Unless someone comes along with something even cleverer.