# How to create shortcut to Rscript on Windows 7

Tags: windows, r, shortcut

I have created a Windows 7 shortcut in an attempt to give someone who is not comfortable with R the ability to run a simple program.  I have tried to follow the advice of other postings, but must be missing something.  This is what I have in my shortcut right now.

Target: `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" --vanilla -e "C:\Users\Moo\Desktop\CharCalendar.r"`

Start in: `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\x64"`

I get error messages (that flash up very briefly on a black DOS window) that say things like `Error unexpected input in "C:\"`

I have tried with and without quotes in the target, I have tried using source() in the target (also with and without quotes).

The script runs without error when I submit it in the R console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" --vanilla C:\Users\Moo\Desktop\CharCalendar.r
```

as your target. No `-e`; that specifies an *expression* to run, not a script file.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit, I hardly ever made my own shortcut in Windows. However, you coul seemly write a bat-file which runs the R-script and PAUSES, so you can read the output:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" "C:\Users\Moo\Desktop\CharCalendar.r"
PAUSE
```

You may also want to add additional options and arguments after `Rscript.exe`. If you want to pass it to `Rgui.exe`, it will be a trickier. Read the following stackoverflow-topic for hints:

[Passing script as parameter to RGui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944970/passing-script-as-parameter-to-rgui)

Comment: I didn't try this, since I got it working with the answer from @HongOoi.  Thanks for the ideas, though.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Rscript.exe -e` with `Rterm.exe -f`, which indicates that you are passing a file as argument, `-e` is for passing expressions e.g. `Rscript.exe -e "a<-1:10; mean(a);"` Rterm provides a few more options for control compared to Rscript, see `Rterm.exe --help`.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work unless I took the -f out as @HongOoi suggested.

Comment: @Hong Ooi You are right, thx for pointing this out, I was thinking of Rterm. I amended my answer.