# 'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: r, batch-file, rstudio

I'm trying to create a bat file that will, among other things, create a .pdf report using RStudio at the end of it, I'm currently using this line

```
R -e "base.path <- 'C:\\temp'; rmarkdown::render('c:\\temp\\report\\report.Rmd')" > C:\temp\log_r.txt 2> C:\temp\log_r_err.txt
```

Now, if I run this line through the command prompt, it works like a charm, but when I put this line inside a .bat file, I get the error in the title.

I already checked the environment variables, to make sure that RStudio is in the path, but let me know if I'm forgetting something else here.

Edit: the other answers that I found here were unable to solve my problem.

Comment: You say RStudio is in the path, but this is irrelevant. Is R in your path?

Comment: You want to execute an R script in batch mode. Instead of using `R`, try calling the script with `Rscript`, preferably by including the entire path to Rscript, e.g., "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.0\bin\x64\Rscript.exe".

Comment: See, e.g., these threads ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3506007/4770166) , [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724875/how-to-create-shortcut-to-rscript-on-windows-7)) for more information.

Comment: @RHertel, sorry, R is in the path as well.
I did try passing the whole path to Rscript.exe but then I got a new error:
Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found.

Comment: Congratulations, the error message means that you have succeeded in running the script with `Rscript`! The error that you are describing does not seem to be an issue that is related to the call through a command prompt. Rather, it seems to be related to `knitr` and some settings of environment variables. See eg. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432607/pandoc-version-1-12-3-or-higher-is-required-and-was-not-found-r-shiny) and [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Error-pandoc-version-1-12-3-or-higher-is-required-and-was-not-found-td4712689.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, it seems to be leading somewhere. I followed the instructions on setting the enviroment variable at the start of the script and now I get this:
`pandoc.exe: pdflatex not found. pdflatex is needed for pdf output.
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 41`

Comment: I did try putting the pdflatex.exe in the enviroment variables but I still got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was able to solve it, after the last message showed up I kept track of every possible path environment variable and I got this final list:

```
[PATH]\R\R-3.3.0\bin\x64
[PATH]\RStudio\bin\x64
[PATH]\RStudio\bin\pandoc
[PATH]\Rtools\bin
[PATH]\texlive\2015\bin\win32
```

Textlive can be replaced by any other LaTeX software.