Are there command line arguments to Rgui.exe for setting the start directory and maximizing the layout?
When I view the Properties of R, on my Windows 11 machine, I see the following:

Evidently, RGui takes the argument "--sdi". I'm guessing there are also arguments to specify the 'Start in' directory, and to run 'Maximized'. What are those arguments? And is there documentation that specifies all such arguments?

You can see all the arguments to Rgui by running Rgui --help at a command prompt. Courtesy of here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944970/passing-script-as-parameter-to-rgui

I ran Rgui --help before posting. It does not mention the --sdi option, and has nothing on start directory or running maximized. I'm pretty sure it's incomplete.

The code that looks at command line options is here: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/4a5e54e99fa50a9daa12e8d35b9b6b1ab40bf63a/src/gnuwin32/system.c#L1224 .  If you're not familiar with C, the expression !strcmp(*av, "--help") will be true if the current argument is "--help".
The list of options that I see is as follows:
--help, -h, --cd-to-userdocs, --no-environ, --ess, --internet2, --mdi, --sdi, --no-mdi, --debug, --workspace=.  As you know, not all of these are documented, so they may be subject to change -- but I don't think Rgui is under active development, just maintenance.  It hasn't changed in many years.
I don't see any arguments to do what you want.  However, there are other ways to achieve it.  You can set up a profile file (see ?Startup) and run commands when R starts.  For example,
setwd("startdir")

The Rconsole file contains a lot of preferences regarding the display window.  You can edit it by hand (it's an ASCII file) or use the preferences dialog to make changes and save it.
