# Running R from Excel VBA without RExcel

Tags: r, vba, excel

Can this process be simplified?

**First, I manually open this file in R:**
C:\R\ExampleModel\ModelScript.R

**From R-Editor, when the code below is run from the open ModelScript.R file, it processes the Model.R script correctly.**

```
source("C:\\R\\ExampleModel\\Model.R", echo=T)
```

*Within Excel, I want to run the source code above without manually opening ModelScript.R from R first. Is there anything I can modify in the VBA code below to process the source() command automatically from Excel/VBA? If a batch process is the only option, short of Rexcel, please use the example extensions provided.*

***Excel 2007 VBA code:***

```
Sub RRUN()

    Dim rCommand As String
    rCommand = "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.0.0\\bin\\Rscript.exe --verbose C:\\R\\ExampleModel\\ModelScript.R"

    'Timer Set to run full Model.R script
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    'Runs R Script and Arguements into process
    Shell rCommand, vbNormalFocus

    'Timer Set to run full Model.R Script
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

End Sub
```

Note: I tried using R.exe in place of Rscript.exe above, with no results.

Comment: Although useful, the Excel R wiki doesn't explain how... http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips%3adata-io%3ams_windows&s=excel

Comment: Not sure you need the escaped backslashes in the path to the executable.

Comment: The above VBA code does run the Rscript.exe and R.exe with the above format Tim. For a simple plot to pdf it works fine...I'm trying to get it to work on a more complicated multiple function code block.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788928/how-to-run-a-r-language-r-file-using-batch-file would work for you

Comment: Tim: need something more specific...but thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into [Visual Studio Tools for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx).   For Excel 2007, the VSTO link is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2tx7z6d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Here's an [example](http://sharpstatistics.co.uk/stats/more-than-macros/) of R within Excel (written using VTSO code).   Look at the section titled "Other Applications".   Here's another [example](http://sharpstatistics.co.uk/extend-excel/) from the same people.   I have no idea if they sell those applications, or if everything is custom made.

Here's another possible [solution](http://sourceforge.net/p/excelsir/wiki/Home/).   I haven't pursued this method because my application has very specific requirements.

My point is, even though you can put something together using VBA, it looks like there are better schemes.

Answer (score 1):

The following appears to work:

Make sure that rscript.exe is in your system PATH

Make sure that your inverted commas in the path= statement work for the filenames. I have left it exactly as the one I now have running rather than make it generic (and more confusing).

```
Sub RunRscript()
Dim shell As Object
Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
Dim style As Integer: style = 1
Dim errorCode As Integer
Dim path As String
path = "rscript ""C:\Users\Charles\SkyDrive\Documents\Development\G4H\Technical evaluation templates\Graphical analysis.R"""
errorCode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)

End Sub
```

This was put together using code from http://shashiasrblog.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/vba-front-end-for-r.html, and with advice from MrFlick. From what I can see it should also be pretty generic.