# How can I execute an external program with parameters in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have read this answer [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673967/how-to-run-exe-in-powershell-with-parameters-with-spaces-and-quotes) answer and it get's me there half way. Here is what I need to do.

Execute this command:

```
"c:\myexe.exe <c:\Users\Me\myanswerfile.txt"
```

If I run that straight from within my powershell script

```
&'c:\myexe.exe <c:\Users\Me\myanswerfile.txt'
```

I get this error:

```
The term 'C:\myexe.exe <c:\Users\Me\myanswerfile.txt' is not recognized as the name of
a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,or 
if a path was included, verif that the path is correct and try again.
```

Now I have tried several variations of this including placing the original command in a variable called $cmd and then passing the

If I append the '<' to the $cmd variable the command fails with a similar error as the first one.

I'm stumped. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to run a program, just type its name and parameters:

```
notepad.exe C:\devmy\hi.txt
```

If you want to run an exe and redirect stdin to it which your example seems to be an attempt of, use:

```
Get-Content c:devmy\hi.txt | yourexe.exe
```

If you need to specify the full path to the program then you need to use ampersand and quotes otherwise powershell thinks you are defining a plain string:

```
&"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
```

Answer (score 10):

Simply use `&` operator

```
& "Program\path\program.exe" "arg1" "arg2" ....
```

Comment: important to notice, it is safer to ALWAYS surround all parameters for external program with double quotes, otherwise very strange and unexpected results may emerge