# Python not working in PowerShell to type script

Tags: python, powershell

I get this error when I type `python`:

[image: screenshot]

```
PS C:\Users\zephy> python
python : Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Python 3.6.5 (v...ntel)] on win32:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Type "help"
, "copyright", "
c
redits" or "license" for more information.
>
>>
```

and I clicked "add to path" when I installed the program.

This is the current path:

C:\Users\zephy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32

Any suggestions? It will run the programs I create fine, but I just can't run any script lines as this doesn't load.

Comment: Please copy and paste the errors as text in the question, not just a screenshot.

Comment: Meanwhile, it's very hard to read scaled-down red-on-blue text, but it looks like you're starting up the interpreter just fine—at least I see the banner and the `>>>` prompt, although it looks like you hit enter a few times while it was in the middle of starting up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I execute an external program with parameters in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478535/how-can-i-execute-an-external-program-with-parameters-in-powershell)

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 0):

I was apparently running Powershell ISE

and not

Powershell.

I guess there was a difference. So much for my first day of trying to code.

Thanks for the suggestions.